# How do I select tags with XPATH based on their relational position?

Tags: xml, xpath

I'm new to XPATH and trying to figure out how to select tags from the following code:

```
                                <content>
                                    <par>
                                        <include.text>
                                            <RefControl/>
                                        </include.text>
                                        <linebreak/>
                                        <include.text>
                                            <RefControl/>
                                        </include.text>
                                        <linebreak/>
                                        <include.text>
                                            <RefControl/>
                                        </include.text>
                                        <linebreak/>
                                        <include.text>
                                            <RefControl/>
                                        </include.text>, T3C</par>
                                </content>
```

I can select the first `<include.text>` tag using the following XPATH: `//include.text[not(preceding-sibling::node())]`.

I am OK with this (I need it this way to differentiate from `<include.text>` tags that are used differently in the XML).

So what XPATH expressions do I need:

1) An XPATH expression that selects the `<linebreak>` tag NOT based on `<par>` (in this case) but based on immediately following `<include.text>`. I would have thought something like this: `//include.text/preceding-sibling::linebreak` but it doesn't work.

2) An XPATH expression that selects the `<include.text>` tags that do NOT immediately follow `<par>`. I can't use "no preceding-sibling" (as above) because there ARE preceding siblings. I need to still be able to differentiate from ALL `<include.text>` tags used in different positions in the XML, however (so also no `//include.text`).

Note: `<par>` is arbitrary (it could be another tag name, too), so I can't use it in the XPATH.

I hope I have explained this clearly. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Also, from this question and your last one, it's clear that your understanding and communication in this area would be improved by realizing that XPath selects at the level of nodes, including *elements*, not opening or closing tags.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! I know I still have a lot to learn about Xpath and this helps my understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### XPath for

1. Selecting all `linebreak` elements whose immediately preceding *element* sibling is `include.text`:

   ```
   //linebreak[preceding-sibling::*[1][self::include.text]]
   ```
2. Selecting `include.text` elements based upon their sibling position:

   `//par/include.text[1]` selects the first `include.text` sibling of a `par` parent.

   `//include.text[1]` selects the first `include.text` sibling, regardless of heritage.

   `//include.text[not(preceding-sibling::*)]` selects the `include.text` only if there are no previous nodes of any kind.

   `//include.text[not(preceding-sibling::node())]` selects the `include.text` only if there are no previous elements.